# Can we upload a AAB file on google play console which is above 150 M.B in size?

Tags: android, android-studio, publish, android-app-bundle

I tried uploading my app on google play console but it shows error that the file size is above 150 M.B. Is there any solution to this problem???

Comment: Did you see the blue section from: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle and follow the [instructions for compressed size](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#size_restrictions)?

Comment: My app uses many Pdf which are very large. Thats why the size of my app is above 1 G.B. Also, I can not make a OBB file

Comment: I would look at [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery) to see if it fits the use case.